# UICollectionView registerClass: forCellWithReuseIdentifier method breaks UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What's the role of `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method? 
According to Apple's developer documentation it's supposed to

> "Register a class for use in creating new collection view cells."

When I try to use it my project I get a black collection view. When I delete it everything works fine.

```
#define cellId @"cellId"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Cell.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray * photoArray;


@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"%@",_photoArray);
    _photoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId];
    for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        NSString * imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i];
        UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
        [_photoArray addObject:img];
    }
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _photoArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Cell* cell = [_collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellImage.image = [_photoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is your collection view being created in IB?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you've already created your UICollectionView in Storyboard, connected your `dataSource` and `delegate`, and you have added all of the required methods:

- `numberOfItemsInSection`
- <del>`numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`</del> (not a required method - [refer to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865196/uicollectionview-registerclass-forcellwithreuseidentifier-method-breaks-uicolle/12884938#comment23861991_12884938))
- `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Then the `registerClass` / `registerCell` method isn't required. However, if you need to reuse a view, data, or cells then you should use those methods so that iOS can populate your UICollectionView as needed. This can also be done in your Storyboard by setting the **Prototype Cell** (the same principle as the `registerClass` method).

Also, if you're looking for a good explanation on what `registerCell` does and how to use it check out [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_6_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout) and scroll to the bottom section titled "Cell and View Reuse."

Comment: Thanks @RazorSharp.  However, would just like to point out `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` is not a 'required method'. As per [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012175-CH1-SW5), `If you do not implement this method, the collection view uses a default value of 1.`

Comment: @SoOverIt Good point! I had forgotten that, please check out my edit.

Comment: The main point is that you can connect a prototype cell directly in a storyboard, which fulfills the same role as calling `registerClass:...`. Memory usage or cell reuse don't really have anything to do with this. A collection view never loads cells into memory that aren't on screen, and if the cell identifier wasn't actually registered, the line where he dequeues a cell would crash.

Comment: Perfect Answer!! save lots of my time Thank you SAM!!

Answer (score 4):

Agree with [RazorSharp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865196/uicollectionview-registerclass-forcellwithreuseidentifier-method-breaks-my-coll/12884938#12884938) and wanted to point out that that key phrase for me in the [Techtopia link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_6_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout) is:

> If the cell class was written in code, the registration is performed using the registerClass: method of UICollectionView, otherwise use registerNib