# How do I set a different height for each UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I feel like this should be a lot easier than it is. All I want to do is have a different height for each of my collection view's cells (depending on the size of the label inside each cell). I'm using `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, but the trouble is figuring out the height before the cell is created.

**What I have now:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // target width of each cell - widht of the collectionView
    let targetWidth: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width - 20.0

    // setup a prototype cell
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCustomCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    // for the sake of simplicity, let's just assume data is coming from somewhere else
    cell.nameLabel.text = data.name
    cell.notesLabel.text = data.notes

    // resize - layoutSubviews in LocationCell controller
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    // get the size based on constraints
    var size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

    // force width
    size.width = targetWidth

    return size
}
```

What's not working is `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`. I'm guessing it's because the `UICollectionViewCell` is not yet available? I also tried [`registerClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865196/uicollectionview-registerclass-forcellwithreuseidentifier-method-breaks-uicolle) to get that, but that doesn't seem to work either. :(

Is there an easier way to do this entirely? All I need to do is figure out what the height is for the cell before it's created. I need an instance of the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass in order to even be able to start (so I can actually access the label and try to determine a height). Been stuck on this for hours. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method

```
 func heightForComment(comment:NSString,font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let rect = NSString(string: comment).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Still seems that I should be able to calculate the height based on an actual cell, or it should be more intuitive, but I guess that's not the case. :(  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper way to do this, but works for me

use this function to obtain the size of the text

```
func labelSize(texto: NSString) -> CGRect {
        var atributos = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)]
        var labelSize = texto.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(280, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: atributos, context: nil)
        return labelSize
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like this may work, so thanks. I'm just concerned that this could get really messy in a complex layout. There's got to be a way since there are collection views being used all over the place with different sized cells.