# collectionview custom cell didn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I create `collectionview` with custom cell and it works correct, but when I update in app it doesn't work, I don't know why.

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CellItem class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellItem"];
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CellItem* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellItem"
                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];
   //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   NSDictionary* celldata = [productsDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString* productName = [celldata objectForKey:@"name"];
   NSString* productImage = [celldata objectForKey:@"image"];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: productImage]];
      if (data == nil)
        return;
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??

       cell.imageViewProduct.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

        //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithData: data]];
      });
  });
  [cell.lableTitle setText:productName];
  return cell;
}
```

and that for itemcell class:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *lableTitle;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewProduct;
```

Image of output here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcZaw.jpg

Comment: Everything seems to be correct, just check if `productImage` has a valid image url

Comment: no it's valid and label title has string

Comment: Seems everything is correct,
try setImage: instead of .image .
And also check Class of customCell.Did you set it or not

Comment: please goes through this link ,it may helps  you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865196/uicollectionview-registerclass-forcellwithreuseidentifier-method-breaks-uicolle

Comment: @mohamedelmaazy, please post the image url, i.e., value of `productImage` ( `NSString* productImage = [celldata objectForKey:@"image"];` ), May be the url is not valid, hit the url in browser and check if the image is displaying or not

Comment: @saif image link work fine

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CellItem class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellItem"];
```

you're use custom UICollectionViewCell so you should not use `registerClass`

Comment: All classes which going to be used in collection views have to be registered before

Comment: I'm saying if you use XIB file instead of prototypecell.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865196/uicollectionview-registerclass-forcellwithreuseidentifier-method-breaks-uicolle/12884938#12884938

check this tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

check "Creating custom UICollectionViewCells" section

Comment: Put a breakpoint in 
`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to check whether code was excused?

Comment: @LuanNguyen did it all excuted

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use register nib function instead of register class.

[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Your cell nib name" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"your cell identifier"];

Let me know if its working for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard try to add one prototype cell to collection view. Then in identity inspector specify your class and in attribute inspector cell identifier.

Example for UITableView (Same as UICollectionView):
[image]
[image]

Comment: @mohamedelmaazy are sure that collection view is connected to the code?

Comment: code from cellitem.m work fine when cell intalized BUT not work in set values